# How update the column value of the first array-list from the second array-list after Comparing two array-list

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have two arraylists. First arraylist contains three column. Product code, name and quantity. This arraylist contains 600 products. And initially quantity for all the products are 0. Now second arraylists have two columns. Product code and Quantity. Seconds arraylist contains 5 products and have different quantity. Now I want to show all the products of the first arraylists with three coloums but the quantity of the products in the first arraylists will be replaced by the second arraylist if the product codes are same and all the products will be populated in a spinner. I have tried following code. Need help in this regard

```
private void populateSpinner() {
    lables = new ArrayList<String>();
    quanty = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    sl = new ArrayList<String>();
    s_q = new ArrayList<String>();
    s_pcode = new ArrayList<String>();
    db = new DatabaseHandler(Offlineordupdate.this);
    arrayList = db.getProductdetails();
    arrayList2 = db.getsavedProductdetails();

    int h = 0;

    if (arrayList.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            sl.add(arrayList.get(i).getproductsl());
            lables.add(arrayList.get(i).getproductname());
            p_code.add(arrayList.get(i).getproductcode());
            PROD_RATE.add(arrayList.get(i).getproductrate());
            PROD_VAT.add(arrayList.get(i).getproductvat());
            nameSerialPair.put(arrayList.get(i).getproductname(), Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(i).getproductsl()));

            if (arrayList2.size() != 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arrayList2.size(); j++) {
                    s_pcode.add(arrayList.get(i).getproductcode());
                    s_q.add(arrayList2.get(j).getproductquant());
                    Log.d("Saved Product details", "" + s_pcode + s_q);
                }
            }

            if (p_code.equals(s_pcode)) {
                int p_serial = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(i).getproductsl());
                mapQuantity.put(p_serial, String.valueOf(arrayList2.get(i).getproductquant()));    
            }

            int p_serial = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(i).getproductsl());
            mapQuantity.put(p_serial, String.valueOf(arrayList.get(i).getproductquant()));
        }
    }

    if (arrayList2.size() != 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayList2.size(); j++) {

            mapQuantity.put(p_serial, String.valueOf(arrayList.get(j).getproductquant()));
        }
    }

    adapter = new OfflineProductListupdateAdapter(Offlineordupdate.this, sl , lables, mapQuantity);
    productListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to put a left join in your database level to form the `ArrayList` to be passed later to the Spinner instead of fetching them both and then joining them again. Here's the left join sql may look like in your case.

```
SELECT Product.ProductName, Product.Code, SavedProduct.Quantity
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN SavedProduct
ON Product.Code = SavedProduct.Code
ORDER BY Product.ProductName;
```

Now you have the list sorted from your database by product name having the quantity along with your cursor. The products which are not saved in your database or doesn't have any quantity will have `null` values in their `Quantity` column which you can easily replace with 0 when you are making a list from the result of your database query.

Hope that helps!